# Firebase reads don't match up to amount of queries I use

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I wrote code with swift and firebase in order to fetch recent posts for my app. However, whenever I perform the query my reads are high. I loaded the app (3 reads as it automatically fetches the posts array, the user document, etc.). Then when I refresh the feed 6 times, it performs 6 queries (below) so a total of 9 reads. However, once i refreshed the Firebase Firestore Usage Tab, my reads were 37. I'm just really confused. How can I fix this so in the future it doesnt multiply into a huge issue.

```
  func getFollowingPosts(startAfter: DocumentSnapshot? = nil, completion: @escaping ([postModel]) -> Void) {
        
        let userIDs = (currentUser?.following)!
        print(userIDs)
        
        let postsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
            .whereField("userID", in: userIDs)
            .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(to: 1)
        
        if let startAfter = startAfter {
            postsRef.start(afterDocument: startAfter)
        }
        
        postsRef.getDocuments { (postsQuerySnapshot, postsError) in
            guard let postsDocuments = postsQuerySnapshot?.documents else {
                // Handle the case where there is an error retrieving the posts
                print("errorwhileretrievingposts")
                completion([])
                return
            }
            
            let posts = postsDocuments.compactMap { document -> postModel? in
                 let data = document.data()
                 let userID = data["userID"] as? String ?? ""
                 let username = data["username"] as? String ?? ""
                 let userProfile = data["userProfile"] as? String ?? ""
                 ...
                  
                 return postModel(userID: userID, username: username, userProfile: userProfile, ...)
             }
             
             completion(posts)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Document limit here is set to `1`; where do you get three reads from?

Comment: Are you accessing your data through the Firebase console at all?

Comment: @trndjc I meant 3 from other uses such as fetching the current user document, which has the logged in user's profile pic, bio data, etc.

Comment: @Jay no, for this I made sure I didn't access the data from console.